# ASP.NET Get text position in px from anchor

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, html, anchor

I have unusual task, I have to get text position in px(x,y) from anchor but I don't have a clue on how to do that:

Here is image of anchor:

[image]

Here is code:

```
<a id="anchor" href="#" runat="server" style="display: inline-block; border-color: #000000; text-decoration: none; border-style: solid; border-width: 1px; background-repeat:no-repeat; width:100px; height:50px;">Text</a>
```

Is there any way to this in ASP.NET or/and JavaScript? I was thinking about wraping span around text and getting offsetWidth/offsetHeight with js but that would only get me size, not position of text in anchor.

**UPDATE: Wild Results**

I changed code a bit:

```
    <div style="display:inline-block;">
                    <p class="category-label" align="center">Normal state preview</p>
                    <a id="anchor" href="#" runat="server" style="display: inline-block; border-color: #000000; text-decoration: none; border-style: solid; border-width: 1px; background-repeat:no-repeat; font-family:Arial; font-size:10px; color:#000000; width:100px; height:50px;">
                    <div runat="server" id="anchorText">Text</div></a>
                </div>

<input type="hidden" id="anchorTextTop" runat="server" />
<input type="hidden" id="anchorTextLeft" runat="server" />
```

Here is Js I use:

```
 function GetTextPosition() {

        var TextTop = document.getElementById('<%= anchorText.ClientID %>').offsetParent.offsetTop;
        var TextLeft = document.getElementById('<%= anchorText.ClientID %>').offsetParent.offsetLeft;

        document.getElementById('<%= anchorTextTop.ClientID %>').value = TextTop;
        document.getElementById('<%= anchorTextLeft.ClientID %>').value = TextLeft;
    }
```

values Im getting:

anchorTextTop = 78 (can't be it's only few pixels from top)
anchorextLeft = 541 (can't be it's 5x size of anchor)

if I use this in js:

```
var TextTop = document.getElementById('<%= anchorText.ClientID %>').offsetTop;
var TextLeft = document.getElementById('<%= anchorText.ClientID %>').offsetLeft;
```

I'm getting:

anchorTextTop = 100 
anchorextLeft = 201

Can this be because controls are marked runat="server"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot get the position of the text inside of an element. You will need to wrap the text in a `<span>` (or an inline `<div>`) and get the `.offsetTop/.offsetLeft` of the `<span>`. To make the offsets relative to the parent, set the parent to `position: relative;`.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/wC4St/

HTML:

```html
<div style="display:inline-block;">
    <p id="category-label" align="center">Normal state preview</p>
    <a id="anchor" href="#" runat="server" style="display: inline-block; border-color: #000000; text-decoration: none; border-style: solid; border-width: 1px; background-repeat:no-repeat; font-family:Arial; font-size:10px; color:#000000; width:100px; height:50px;">
    <span runat="server" id="anchorText">Text</span></a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
#anchor {
    position: relative;   
    text-align: center; 
}
```

Script:

```js
document.getElementById( 'category-label' ).textContent = 
      'left: ' + document.getElementById( 'anchorText' ).offsetLeft 
    + ' top: ' + document.getElementById( 'anchorText' ).offsetTop;
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for clering it up, I tried with div(not inline) and didn't set parent to relative,s o that must be it.I will try this code and get back with results.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to do this with client side script because the page needs to be rendered by the browser before you can deal with layout dimensions.

how you calculate the position depends on what you want the position to be relative to. the offsetTop and offsetHeight values are relative to the offsetParent of the element.

If you want  the position of the element relative to the document then you can walk up the recursive offsetParent properties until a null value and a increment the offsetTop and offsetLeft properties.

```
function getPosition()
{
    var element = document.getElementById("anchor");
    var position = {};
    position.top = element.offsetTop;
    position.left = element.offsetLeft;
    return position;
}
```

Comment: I need offset to parent, I didn't even know about offsetTop seems like that would be exactly what I need!

Comment: It is a good code but I'm somehow getting wild results..I'll update up so you can check it out.